# git-p4 and huge file sizes

Tags: filesystems, git, repository, perforce, apfs

I am trying to convert a Perforce(p4) repository to git (preferably to Helix4Git, a git server implementation by perforce).

I reduce my problem to a simple use-case in order to find the solution for my bigger problem.

In P4 I have one file **//depot/foo.txt** which is 10MB. I "cloned" it by using the merge command of P4 so I have the same file twice in my repository, called **//depot/bar.txt**.

```
//depot
    .. foo.txt (10MB) [internal-id==> 4509b9a8.txt]
    .. bar.txt (10MB, clone of foo.txt) [internal-id==> 4509b9a8.txt]
```

The P4 server stores the file **once** by using two links internally to reduce used disk space so just 10MB are used. On a local disk I would have two physical copies though (10+10=20MB). Now here is problem:

I use *git-p4* to convert my P4 repository to git. First I clone it to my local computer, and then set a git-remote and submit everything to finally have it on my git server.

As mentioned earlier, I have 20MB on my local disk and when I submit it to my git server he uses 20MB as well.

1) If I clone a file in git, is it physically cloned on the server as well?

2) Is there any chance that git-p4 or the git server detects this "clone" - that it is the same file - and uses links internally as well? Either the git server itself or by using a file system feature (soft-link or hard-link, etc).

Extra Question) Would macOS APFS for the git server be of any help here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you moved the cloned files into Git, they will be stored **separately**. Git only stores the file content and file permissions. Metadata and inode ID is not tracked.

Your best bet to add the clone to `gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`

Reference: [enter link description here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Does_Git_track_all_file_data_and_metadata.3F)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't want to ignore the files. I need them on my server. I am aware that git without extensions has some problems with big files but is is really that bad? We have ~200 branches with thousands of source code files with 1 MB of size. Several of them are plain copies so I try to find a workaround to not pollute the git server with physical unnecessary copies